# Create an UIImage by pdf file in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

[use the pdf as icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3OVK.png)

when i want to use the pdf icon in project,i do like this

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_file_open"];
```

but is that ok? `[UIImage imageNamed:]` will always retain the image in memory,is there any other way that i can create the image by pdf?

Comment: use contentsoffile instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have put your pdf in your `assets` your `scale factor` (from `attribute inspector`) is set to `single vector` and then you getting your image like,

```
  [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_file_open"];
```

here `icon_file_open` is name of that imageset of asset,

then it is the standard way of using single vector pdf. So this is the case then it is fine!

make sure that your pdf's size is `1x`, xcode automatically manage `2x and 3x` from it!

you can refer [this tutorial](http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/) or [this tutorial](https://icons8.com/articles/how-to-use-vectors-in-xcode-7/) for more details!

Comment: thanks,but  use  [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_file_open"]  the UIImage will remain in memory,is there any other to way to create UIImage by using pdf and the UIImage created doesn't remain in memory?

Comment: you can set `image = nil` for that!!